# Trisquel 7.0 LTS Belenos 64 vs Ubuntu 15.04 64 or Mac OS X 10.10.5 : isl/gcc problem (libisl.so.13 incriminated)

Tags: gcc, trisquel

I installed last 64bits trisquel distro recently, I build gcc 5.2.0 from source on it. I used exactly the same installation technique than the one I used (and that worked) on ubuntu 15.04 64bits, which is the following, and uses isl and cloog optimizations for gcc :

```
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gmp/gmp-6.0.0a.tar.xz

tar -Jxf gmp-6.0.0a.tar.xz

cd gmp-6.0.0/

mkdir build && cd build

../configure --prefix=/usr/local/lvm/gmp-6.0.0 --enable-cxx

make -j 4

sudo make install

sudo make check

cd ..

cd ..

wget http://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-3.1.2/mpfr-3.1.2.tar.gz

tar xvzf mpfr-3.1.2.tar.gz

cd mpfr-3.1.2

mkdir build && cd build

../configure --prefix=/usr/local/lvm/mpfr-3.1.2 --with-gmp=/usr/local/lvm/gmp-6.0.0

make -j 4

sudo make install

cd ..

cd ..

wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/mpc/mpc-1.0.3.tar.gz

tar xvzf mpc-1.0.3.tar.gz

cd mpc-1.0.3

mkdir build && cd build

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lvm/gmp-6.0.0/lib:/usr/local/lvm/mpfr-3.1.2/lib ../configure --prefix=/usr/local/lvm/mpc-1.0.3 --with-gmp=/usr/local/lvm/gmp-6.0.0 --with-mpfr=/usr/local/lvm/mpfr-3.1.2

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lvm/gmp-6.0.0/lib:/usr/local/lvm/mpfr-3.1.2/lib make -j 4

sudo make install

cd ..

cd ..

wget http://isl.gforge.inria.fr/isl-0.14.tar.gz

tar xvzf isl-0.14.tar.gz

cd isl-0.14/

mkdir build && cd build

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lvm/gmp-6.0.0/lib ../configure --prefix=/usr/local/lvm/isl-0.14 --with-gmp-prefix=/usr/local/lvm/gmp-6.0.0

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lvm/gmp-6.0.0/lib make -j 4

sudo make install

cd ..

cd ..

wget "http://www.bastoul.net/cloog/pages/download/cloog-0.18.4.tar.gz"

tar xvzf cloog-0.18.4.tar.gz

cd cloog-0.18.4

mkdir build && cd build

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lvm/isl-0.14/lib:/usr/local/lvm/gmp-6.0.0/lib ../configure -prefix=/usr/local/lvm/cloog-0.18.4 --with-isl-prefix=/usr/local/lvm/isl-0.14 --with-gmp-prefix=/usr/local/lvm/gmp-6.0.0

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lvm/isl-0.14/lib:/usr/local/lvm/gmp-6.0.0/lib make -j 4

sudo make install

cd ..

cd ..

wget ftp://ftp.irisa.fr/pub/mirrors/gcc.gnu.org/gcc/releases/gcc-5.2.0/gcc-5.2.0.tar.gz

tar xvzf gcc-5.2.0.tar.gz

cd gcc-5.2.0

mkdir build && cd build

# I DON'T PASS  --disable-multilib

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lvm/gmp-6.0.0/lib:/usr/local/lvm/mpfr-3.1.2/lib:/usr/local/lvm/mpc-1.0.3/lib:/usr/local/lvm/isl-0.14/lib:/usr/local/lvm/cloog-0.18.4/lib ../configure --prefix=/usr/local/lvm/gcc-5.2.0 --enable-checking=release --with-gmp=/usr/local/lvm/gmp-6.0.0 --with-mpfr=/usr/local/lvm/mpfr-3.1.2 --with-mpc=/usr/local/lvm/mpc-1.0.3 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --with-isl=/usr/local/lvm/isl-0.14 --with-cloog=/usr/local/lvm/cloog-0.18.4 --program-suffix=-5.2.0

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lvm/gmp-6.0.0/lib:/usr/local/lvm/mpfr-3.1.2/lib:/usr/local/lvm/mpc-1.0.3/lib:/usr/local/lvm/isl-0.14/lib:/usr/local/lvm/cloog-0.18.4/lib make -j 4

sudo make install
```

After that, I wanted to test some c++11 features, so I create a tst_lambda.cpp file containing this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << [](int m, int n) { return m + n;} (2,4) << endl;
    vector<int> V({1,2,3});
    cout << "V =" << endl;
    for(auto e : V)
    {
        cout << e << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and build an executable with :

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lvm/gmp-6.0.0:/usr/local/lvm/mpfr-3.1.2:/usr/local/lvm/mpc-1.0.3:/usr/local/lvm/cloog-0.18.4:/usr/local/lvm/isl-0.14:/usr/local/lvm/gcc-5.2.0/lib64
export PATH=/usr/local/lvm/gcc-5.2.0/bin/:$PATH
g++-5.2.0 -std=c++11 tst_lambda.cpp -o tst_lambda
```

which triggered, on Trisquel 7.0 LTS Belenos 64bits, the following error :

```
/usr/local/lvm/gcc-5.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.2.0/cc1plus: error while loading shared libraries: libisl.so.13: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I went to see `/usr/local/lvm/gcc-5.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.2.0/cc1plus` and did a `ldd` on it, which gave me what follows :

```
cc1plus:
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffc5df8000)
    libisl.so.13 => not found
    libmpc.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpc.so.3 (0x00007f1ec32fb000)
    libmpfr.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpfr.so.4 (0x00007f1ec309f000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007f1ec2e2b000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f1ec2c26000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f1ec2920000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1ec255b000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f1ec352d000)
```

So I went to see in `/usr/local/lvm/isl-0.14/lib` and found the following elements :

```
total 4912
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3263234 août  11 14:38 libisl.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1000 août  11 14:38 libisl.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 août  11 14:38 libisl.so -> libisl.so.13.1.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 août  11 14:38 libisl.so.13 -> libisl.so.13.1.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1750046 août  11 14:38 libisl.so.13.1.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    3939 août  11 14:38 libisl.so.13.1.0-gdb.py
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 août  11 14:38 pkgconfig
```

and I don't understand : libisl.so.13 points to libisl.so.13.1.0 which is the same directory as the symlink it is pointed by...

Under Ubuntu 15.04 64bits or under Mac OS X 10.10.5, I don't have such a linking problem, the linking is done, libisl.so.13.1.0 is found. Under Trisquel, apparently not... What is the problem ?

Comment: I posted this question in http://unix.stackexchange.com/ as the OS I have problem with is Trisquel, but I am not sure that it is optimal wrt having the biggest gcc community target audience.

Comment: Shouldn't your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` contain `/usr/local/lvm/isl-0.14/lib` and not `/usr/local/lvm/isl-0.14` ?

Comment: Good call... I really should hang myself right now... Sorry. A connex question : i remarked that I need to precise <code>export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lvm/gcc-5.2.0/lib64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH</code> and <code>export PATH=/usr/local/lvm/gcc-5.2.0/bin/:$PATH</code> were sufficient on mac OS X 10.10.5, but not under linux (aforementioned ubuntu and trisquel). Why so ?

Comment: I honestly don't know. Usually, if an app expects its libraries to be at custom locations, it should use -R linking flags to bind themselves to these locations instead of expecting the system to provide them. Or may be MacOS adds those lib locations to ld.so path.

Comment: Fair enough, I prefer btw to flag the libraries paths myself than relying on the OS doing it for me. Except when I should be hanged. ;-) Thx again.